# Bar Chart using AChartEngine in Android

Tags: android, achartengine

I am trying to create a chart in eclipse/android Sdk, i was following different tutorials step by step, but everywhere i have the same problem, that graph doesn't want to show up(i have no errors and i can compile my program). Currently i am using AChartEngine library.
Any suggestions?

```
    package com.example.linegraph;

    import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
    import org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries;
    import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
    import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
    import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class LineGraph {

        public Intent getIntent (Context context)
        {
            int[] x={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
            int[]y={11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,11};

            TimeSeries series =new TimeSeries("Line1");

            for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
            {
                series.add(x[i],y[i]);

            }
            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset =new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
            dataset.addSeries(series);

            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer=new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
            XYSeriesRenderer renderer =new XYSeriesRenderer();
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

            Intent intent=ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer,"Line Graph Title");
            return intent;

        }

    }
```

MainActivity is below

```
        package com.example.linegraph;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }


        public void lineGraphHandler (View view){
        LineGraph line= new LineGraph();
        Intent lineIntent=line.getIntent(this);
        startActivity(lineIntent);


        }
    }
```

The layout xml is below.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    </RelativeLayout>
```

yes, this code should display the graph
there's link on tutorial ->https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ThKImy6PPM
other things ,like textview apeared, excepting graph, mayb i need to install some additional features?

Comment: What did you try? Can you show your layout.xml and other activity files? So users can handle your question on correct way.

Comment: At what stage is `lineGraphHandler` called and why do you pass a `View`?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have any experience with aChartEngine, but your intent stuff I don't completely understand.  I guess that is so that the aChartEngine code itself will display the chart?

The examples I saw actually rendered the chart in your views.  Basically you need a LinearLayout with id chart that it will render into. See:

[JavaAdvent](http://www.javaadvent.com/2012/12/achartengine-charting-library-for.html)

and

[JaxEnter blog](http://jaxenter.com/effort-free-graphs-on-android-with-achartengine-46199.html)